# Strategy for integrating product of powers and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, contour-integration, gamma-function, substitution

I want to compute the simple-looking definite integral $$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\cos\omega t}{t^a}\,dt,\quad 0<a<1\,,$$
but I have no idea where to begin. Mathematica and integration tables give the final result but I want to know the precise steps leading up to it, be it a clever choice of contour or substitution. Many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Gamma function
$$ \Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt $$
for $s=\sigma+i\omega$, one has
$$ \int_0^\infty t^{-a}e^{-st}dt=s^{a-1}\Gamma(1-a)=(\sigma+i\omega)^{a-1}\Gamma(1-a). $$
Letting $\sigma\to0$ gives
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^\infty t^{-a}e^{-i\omega t}dt\\
&=&(i\omega)^{a-1}\Gamma(1-a)\\
&=&e^{\frac{(a-1)\pi i}{2}}\omega^{a-1}\Gamma(1-a)\\
&=&\omega^{a-1}\bigg(\cos\left(\frac{(a-1)\pi }{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{(a-1)\pi }{2}\right)\bigg) \Gamma(1-a)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \int_0^\infty t^{-a}\cos(\omega t)dt=\omega^{a-1}\cos\left(\frac{(a-1)\pi }{2}\right)\Gamma(1-a).  $$

Comment: I think you dropped the $\Gamma$ a bit after letting $\sigma\to0$

Comment: @user170231, thanks.